# IBM Mainframe Assembler - using MVC with a register displacement

Tags: assembly, mainframe

I am working on an assignment for a college assembly class. We are using IBM Mainframe PC370 emulator. (Old school, but great starting point)

I always try to go a little beyond the scope of the assignment in order to better my programming skills.

What I am trying to do is to move some character data (WORD) into (CWORD) with a offset of 1 using a register. My hope is to be able to place data into an index based off of the input from a file to determine the placement in an index.

We have been given a file that has a five digit dollar figure in position 1-5 and a two digit month code in position 20-21. I would like to put the month code in a register to determine the offset to add the dollar amount into that position in the index.

The following code is what I have been using to attempt the register offset.

Is this even possible? I have not found anything in the textbook or online that specifically discusses doing this type of thing.

```
         L     R5,1
         MVC   CWORD+0(R5),WORD
         WTO   CWORD
         WTOR  'PRESS ENTER TO EXIT',EXIT
```

Thank you for your time.
SUBCAN

Comment: Check out http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/360_Assembly and http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/hlasm/library.html?S_CMP=rnav for books you might find useful.

Comment: It would help if you gave the expected input and output record layouts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

```
      L     R5,1                        Get the fullword (32bit) value at location 0001.
      MVC   CWORD+0(R5),WORD            Copy the 5 bytes at location WORD to location CWORD.
      WTO   CWORD                       Display the contents of CWORD.
      WTOR  'PRESS ENTER TO EXIT',EXIT  Display the message and wait for a response.
```

Plus, presumably:

```
CWORD DS    CL5                     Output area.
      ...
WORD  DS    CL4                     Input area
```

You should have written:

```
      LA    R5,CWORD+1                  Get the address of the second byte of CWORD.
      MVC   0(L'WORD,R5),WORD           Copy the Length(WORD) bytes at location WORD to location CWORD+1.
      WTO   CWORD                       Display the contents of CWORD.
      WTOR  'PRESS ENTER TO EXIT',EXIT  Display the message and wait for a response.
      ...
CWORD DS    CL5                     Output area.
WORD  DS    CL4                     Input area
```

At least, that sounds like what you wanted.  But it isn't 100% clear from your question.  If that wasn't your intention.

Answer (score 1):

```
     LA     R5,1
     MVC   CWORD+0(R5),WORD
```

In MVC instruction we provide length and not the register. In your case R5 will be interpreted as 5 since in starting of your program you would have declared R5 EQU 5
so it will move 5 characters and not 1.

If you want to use register use like below
        EX  R5,MOVE
        .
        .
        .
Move    MVC CWORD(0),WORD

so this will replace legnth with the value in R5. In this case you can place value in R5
LA R5,1 will work

Reagrds,
Shashank
Assembler Developer.

Answer (score 0):

> ...move some character data (WORD) into (CWORD) with a offset of 1
>   using a register...

As per the above specification:

```
  [code to establish base register assumed] 
  LA 1,CWORD+1
  MVC 0(L'CWORD-1,1),WORD
  [...]
* assuming WORD and CWORD are both 4-byte fullwords
* only the first three bytes of WORD will fit into CWORD+1
WORD  DS  F 
CWORD DS  F
```